# Alignment of variable in column using shell script.File saved in .json format

Tags: shell, csv

```
myarray=$fruit,$count,$amount >>fruitlist.json
```

Output which I got :

```
"Apple",1,"Rs.50"
"Orange",2,"Rs.500"
"Grapes",3,"Rs.100"
```

Expected Output:

```
 FRUIT   QUANTITY   PRICE
"Apple"      1      "Rs.50"
"Orange"     2      "Rs.500"
"Grapes"     3      "Rs.100"
```

Comment: in a tabular ormat

Comment: Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/521943/edit) your post and clarify what you are running, what your input is and what you want out, because it simply doesn't make sense at the moment. State your question clearly.

Comment: By the nature of the CSV concept, it won't create visually aligned tables. CSV is short for "Comma Seperated Value", which means each value is seperated by a comma. The values can be of different length, and the columns aren't really managed at all. You are confusing a data-storage spec with a text formatting concept.

Comment: Hello x tian ,I have edited the file

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

```
column -t -s',' filename
```

Here','  is file separator, so you can use which is applicable for your file.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate your ans